# Сервера приложений

Tags: java, servlet

Представим, что есть несколько сервлетов(однотипных) написанных на java для предоставлений веб-сервиса по XML-RPC. Необходим сервер приложений на котором они будут крутиться. Первое и самое легкое что приходит в голову это Apache Tomcat. Но для перегрузки одного из сервлетов нужно будет перегружать весь Томкат(прошу поправить если не так).

Нужен полноценный сервер приложений с возможность перегрузки отдельных сервлетов, без перегрузки всего application server. Как альтернативу рассматриваю nginx. Что ещё можете посоветовать?

Comment: Это возможно и с томкатом, загляните сюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583502/how-do-i-update-a-tomcat-webapp-without-restarting-the-entire-service. Ваши сервлеты для этого должны быть реализованы в отдельных WAR-файлах

Answer (score 2):

Перезагружать весь сервер приложений не требуется, нужно лишь перезагрузить приложение, в котором находится искомый сервлет. Возвращаясь к главному вопросу, так просто перезагружать части приложения на сервере не получится. Собственно то, что ты хочешь называется [ESB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F). Есть три популярных открытых решения:

- [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/)
- [Spring integeration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/)
- [MuleEsb](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-open-source-esb)

Плюс множество пропретарных решений. Они как раз позволяют перезагружать компоненты "на лету"